# zsh syntax to expand variables' names matching a prefix

Tags: zsh, variable-substitution

**TL; DR:** is there a `zsh` equivalent of Ksh/Bash's `"${!varnamepfx@}"` expansion?

So that, for example, if I have the following variables `set`:

```bsh
[...]
foo='random value'
bar=$'amazing\n value'
baz='that other value'
[...]
```

then by requesting `printf -- %s\\n "${!ba@}"` in Bash I get:

```bsh
bar
baz
```

I've been perusing the [`zsh` manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html) but [haven't been able](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) to [find anything](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters) direct like the above syntax. The best I could resort to has been the following nested-expansion:

<sup>(for the example above)</sup>

```bsh
printf -- %s\\n "${(M)${${(f)$(set)}[@]%%=*}[@]:#ba*}"
```

It seems to be doing the job reliably (at least on MacOS Catalina's zsh v5.3) but looks quite convoluted and I also wonder whether the `$(set)` Command Substitution in there really spawns a process or is instead optimized by `zsh`.

Admittedly, I have so far ruled out (and thus not looked into) getting that job done through the Completion System as it would seem a bit of an overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option to match on the keys of the [`$parameter` special associative array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-parameters-1) is to use the `I` [subscript flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-subscript-flags):

```
$ print -rC1 - $parameters[(I)ba*]
bar
baz
```

That's an *associative array* operator which results in list/array, while @Gille's `${(kM)parameters:#ba*}` is a *list/array operator* applied to the keys of the associative array also resulting in a list/array. The end result is essentially the same in this case here.

If you have to remember only one, the `${(M)array:#pattern}` which is `grep`-for-arrays is the more useful one as it's more generic. The things it can't do compared to *array subscript flags* is match on keys and return the corresponding values or match on values and return the corresponding keys.

You can combine both like in:

```
$ print -rC1 - ${(Mk)parameters[(R)array*]:#pa*}
path
patchars
```

Here to return the names of arrays that start with `pa` (*values* of `$parameters` are matched against `array*` and *keys* against `pa*`).

Of course, you can do that for all of `zsh`'s introspection variables (`$aliases`, `$commands`, `$functions`, `$builtins`, `$modules`, `$history`...)

For some of them, you can also query using a `-m pattern` (match) option of the corresponding builtin (`whence -m`, `alias -m`, `autoload -m`, `fc -m`...), but like for `bash`'s `compgen`, you can't reliably post-process their output as it's line-based while some of the things they report may contain newline characters.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand it, this idiom remains a direct expansion from array whereas Gilles' (and mine even more) has turned into text-manipulation. Hence eg this one can be simply double-quoted to obtain a `$IFS`-delimited expansion, whereas Gilles' and mine would require additional nesting/flags I suppose.

Comment: @LL3, not really, the `${array:#pattern}` is filtering array members that match the pattern, you still get a list, there's no conversion to scalar. It's only  that if you quote it without adding the `@` flag, that becomes the text operator as you're no longer in list context. In any case, if you want to join array elements with some separator, it's better to use the `j[sep]` parameter expansion flag than having to rely on a global parameter like `$IFS`. `print -r - ${(kMj[, ])parameters:#ba*}` or `print -r - ${(j[, ])parameters[(I)ba*]}`. See also my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Zsh doesn't have special syntax to filter variable names. Just combine the [`parameters` associative array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-parameters-1) with [parameter expansion features](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion): `${(k)…}` to get the keys (which are the parameter names), `${…:#…}` to filter on a pattern, and `${(M)…}` to keep matches rather than remove matches.

```
printf '%s\n' ${(kM)parameters:#ba*}
```